# iPhone Developer Certificate This certificate is invalie

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4.3, keychain

I am new to this development process. It is really frustrating about this Certificate issues in iOS development. Not sure why is not developer friendly. Oneway or the other keep on getting the problems, and sucking unnecessary time.

What is my problem?

1) Have generated Certificate Signing Request from Keychain.

2) Login into the developer.apple.com

3) Creating the provisioning profile by uploading the file.

4) I get the .mobversion file, which i i double click, and it is loaded into this xcode. 
   [ Oh... The same i tried dragging and keeping in the xcode, which was not working, 
     but double click works.]

5) Downloaded .cer file, and when i double click, key chain still shows, that 
   the certificate is not yet valid.

I am really pissed off due to this issue, not sure how to resolve this. Helping would
really be appreciated. It could be a silly mistake from my end  also. Kindly point out.

Comment: Do you have the WWDC-certificate installed?

Comment: 1) I tried installing the same, but still same result. 2) do we really need WWDC certificate to be installed?. because, i remember few months back, i could do without WWDC certificate also?

Comment: wwdc? wwdc was cool but I think you mean wwdr :D

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps:

1. Clear All Previos Provisioning profiles from Organizer.
2. Go to Keychain and And Request certificate and make certificates as procedure.
3. Revoke old certificate from Developer.apple.com and use your new certificate.
4. Make New App Id
5. Make New Provisioning Profile.
6. Use this profile. I hope it will work.